# How to disable google keyboard suggestion for the web input field

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to disable android google keyboard suggestion for the particular text input field in html.
how we can achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

Just set as shown

```
<input autocomplete="off" placeholder="No Auto Complete Or suggestions" />
```

Hope it helps